# Can you use SQL Server Reporting Services, SSRS 2008, to host an intranet site?

Tags: sql-server, iis, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, http.sys

The project I'm on has a single server running both the SQL Server 2008 R2 database and the SSRS Reporting Services.  Can I utilize SSRS to host a simple intranet site that would allow users to modify reference table data via a web app that I created?

I know SSRS is no longer tied directly to IIS.  Is it possible to use SSRS's hosting facilities or will I be forced to install IIS?

I have read articles on how to utilize report parameters to do simple CRUD operations (http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/articles/sql-server-bi/26/using-sql-server-reporting-services-to-manage-data), but I'd prefer another solution, because at some point the data entry piece will be used to do more than manage lookup table data.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: You might want to integrate SSRS with Sharepoint for a more "proper" intranet.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I utilize SSRS to host a simple intranet site that would allow users to modify reference table data via a web app that I created?

Yes you could do that.  From the different elements in a SSRS report you can link to web pages, so the report could link to your web app, then have the web app link back to reports.

Also, one report could link to another report, and you could accomplish an intranet with a dashboard page that links off to dozens of other reports.

> I know SSRS is no longer tied directly to IIS. Is it possible to use SSRS's hosting facilities or will I be forced to install IIS?

In order to just run reports you would need an install of IIS, but in order to run other web applications, you will need a web server, and IIS will do the job.

As far as the data entry goes, you are probably best off using your web application rather than trying to implement data entry in the report.  Technically you can do data entry using parameters on the reports, but it is a very ugly solution.

Still using Sharepoint with SSRS might give you want you want.  Another option would be to use OneNote for some of the intranet pages, and put the OneNote files on a shared network location.  You will still need your web app to enter data.

I hope this answers you question.